# Distribute objects vertically when viewport changes

Tags: css, viewport

I've been sitting at this problem now for about 4h. Way to long I suppose. So here I am:

I would like to distribute div containers vertically as soon as the viewport exceeds a specific height. Here's a [sketch of an example](http://share.axure.com/PUNHKK).

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bubu">
    <div class="center1"></div>
    <div class="center2">
        <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="center3"></div>
    <div class="center4">
        <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="center5"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
body {
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    background: no-repeat fixed center center #030303;
    allowtransparency:true
}
.bubu {
    background-color:#eee;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width:500px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -275px;
    /* width / 2 */
}
.center1 {
    background-color:red;
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width:100%
}
.center2 {
    background-color:yellow;
    position: relative;
    height: 35%;
    width:100%
}
.center3 {
    background-color:red;
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width:100%
}
.center4 {
    background-color:yellow;
    position: relative;
    height: 35%;
    width:100%
}
.center5 {
    background-color:red;
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width:100%
}
.element {
    background-color:#123456;
    position: absolute;
    height: 250px;
    width:500px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top: -125px;
    /* width / 2 */
}
```

Since margin:auto 0; will not do the job (will convert to 0 in height) I tried all different kinds of solutions. [This (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Phe/) is the one that only came close to it.

What I did was basically to add five classes, three of them `height:10%;` and two of them containing my containers `height:35%;`
Everything surrounded by one container `height:100%;`

As you can see, every time the container expands (my example size) off 500px the center expands twice.

How on earth can I solve this??

Comment: What kind of browser support are you looking for?  There are many ways to do this.  How about using some JavaScript or jQuery if needed?

Comment: This should be quite easy with Flexbox, if the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) is acceptable. Otherwise, I would probably use JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry folks I can't use a framework like jQuery since I'm working on low level devices and performance critical environment. We have implemented our own framework for every specific case :-/

Comment: flexbox did the job! Thanks @thirtydot for that!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do some responsive design. 
So what about using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)?

It has a very flexible [Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) system and it works out of the box on the most devices.

Comment: Bootstrap's grid system doesn't really help with this specific problem.